# Honda civic 1.4

Tags: honda, civic, car

My daughter has a w reg Honda civic 1.4. she says there is a rattle from the back when she changes gear & also when dropping engine speed. What could it be? It is Sunday so can't find mechanic.

Comment: What year is the civic and how many miles?

Answer (score 2):

The description doesn't say a lot, it might be anything. To me it seems like the rattle comes from the exhaust. It might be a sound of the engine (shooting vapors of fuel inside of an exhaust) and it is okay, but also it might be exhaust touching any other part of a car, like floor, rear axle, fuel tank etc. That might happen to older exhausts which might crack and change a shape. 
 Get to the back of the car, grab it, and give it a shake. If it is similar sound then you found the issue. If not, I'd like to hear it then.

Comment: Could also be some internal part of the muffler being loose.